# replacement of ApostropheFilterFactory in solr 5.3.1

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I need to remove apostrophe from the words before indexing. For eg I want Bachelor's to become Bachelor . I used solr.ApostropheFilterFactory for that , but I think , this filter got deprecated after solr4 and i am using solr5.
This is how I used it

```
<analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ApostropheFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

I have also used StandardFilterFactory

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Both these are not working for me. Can Anyone suggest me Anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try PatternReplaceFilterFactory?

Comment: I have tried  PatternReplaceFilterFactory but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Use Word Delimiter Filter**

This filter splits tokens at word delimiters.
The rules for determining delimiters are determined as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

- A change in case within a word: "CamelCase" -> "Camel", "Case". This can be disabled by setting splitOnCaseChange="0".
- A transition from alpha to numeric characters or vice versa: "Gonzo5000" -> "Gonzo", "5000" "4500XL" -> "4500", "XL". This can be disabled by setting splitOnNumerics="0".
- Non-alphanumeric characters (discarded): "hot-spot" -> "hot", "spot"
- A trailing "'s" is removed: "O'Reilly's" -> "O", "Reilly"
  Any leading or trailing delimiters are discarded: "--hot-spot--" -> "hot", "spot"

Or

**Classic Filter**

> This filter takes the output of the Classic Tokenizer and strips periods from acronyms and "'s" from possessives.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Note : If you provide type="index" in analyzer tag then analyzer used for index time

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late response , I tried both the above but no luck , If you want I can provide the xml code that i wrote.

Comment: After changed did your reload that core ? or restart solr ? and reindex data ?. If you don't, it will not affect

Comment: I did reload the code , reindexed the data but it didn't work

Comment: It should work. try to test in admin panel analysis tab

Comment: I checked in the admin panel tab , there i can see the WordDelimiterFilterFactory applied on the word 'Bachelor's Degree' and converting it to 'Bachelor degree'. So both in the Field Value (Query) and Field Value (Index) the WordDelimiterFilterFactory is converting the word 'Bachelor's Degree' to 'Bachelor's Degree' , SO why I am getting zero results when quering like this                                                                     -----query?fq=bodyStemmed:"bachelor’%20degree"----

Comment: bodyStemmed is my field name.

Comment: Fq and termfrequency are not showing the correct results

Comment: @gashu if you also want to remove 's from query then you have to remove type="index"

Comment: He @gashu I have tested it with solr-5.5.1 and it's working perfactrly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139834/discussion-between-gashu-and-ashraful-islam).